# Going to the next view in React Navigation stack--without knowing its name

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm working on my first Stack Navigator in React Native. I am wondering what the best way is to have a view go to the next view in the stack, without its needing to know the name.

Right now I'm providing each view in the stack with the entire *this.props.navigation* object and the name of the view it should go to next:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate(nextQuestionName);
```

But I would like to decouple the cards in the stack from having to know anything about neighboring cards. I wonder what the best practice is -- should they rely on a function in the stack navigator that dynamically decides what the next card is? Or is there some built-in function I'm missing, that does this?

The tricky part is that from any given screen, I am having trouble accessing information about the overall navigation stack. I thought maybe the list of all routes might be in the navigate object but I only see:

```
{ dispatch: [Function],
06-23 11:17:49.193  5204  5652 I ReactNativeJS:   state: { routeName: 'AnyoneGoFishing', key: 'Init-id-1498212911329-0' },
06-23 11:17:49.193  5204  5652 I ReactNativeJS:   goBack: [Function: goBack],
06-23 11:17:49.193  5204  5652 I ReactNativeJS:   navigate: [Function: navigate],
06-23 11:17:49.193  5204  5652 I ReactNativeJS:   setParams: [Function: setParams] }
```

From researching online I get the sense that the recommended solution has something to do with dispatching a message to a router, but I am having trouble finding a working example.

UPDATE: For anyone facing the same problem, I found the answer buried in this GitHub issues thread. The answer is to have a generic NextScreen screen that changes based on what data goes to it in params, as opposed to a variable choice of which Screen.

https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1210